# Can't log in to ANY EE site (on only one computer)

Tags: control-panel

Weird problem that is happening only with EE sites one one computer. I manage a number of ExpressionEngine websites and suddenly today I can't log in to any of them. I get the "This form has expired. Please refresh and try again" error message on any EE site I try to log in to. I checked on other computers and can log in just fine, even from my phone which is on the same IP address as my main computer. I have tried all manner of cache clearing (on EE via ftp and in browsers) and cookie clearing, computer restarts, different browsers, many tweaks to config files. Nothing is helping. The only thing that seems to have an effect is if I add "$config['disable_csrf_protection'] = "y";" to the config file - this doesn't allow me to log in, instead I see a "you must enter a username" message, even though a username has been entered. The EE sites I am trying to log in to are all running either version 5.4 or 6+. Any ideas at all???

Answer (score 0):

It could be a stale cookie. Clear your browser history and cookies then try logging in again.

Otherwise open up /system/user/config/config.php and add:

```
$config['cp_session_type'] = 's';
```

This forces control panel logins to use session ID's instead of cookies.

Comment: Thanks, but yup, I sure have tried that and just did again. To be thorough I set $config['cp_session_type'] = 's' then cleared all browser history, including all cookies, cleared EE cache from server and tried logging in. Same message on all EE sites: "This form has expired. Please refresh and try again." Stuck.

Comment: Just want to update this with all the things I have tried so far (too long a list to post, system won't allow).

Answer (score 0):

OP answer: BITDEFENDER developed a sudden hostility to multiple ExpressionEngine sites, many of which I access on a daily basis. When I turn off Bitdefender I am able to access all EE sites again. If you run into this issue save yourself some time and check your anti-virus software first!